# How to pythonicly create a dictionary of highscores from a list of scores

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

In python, assume I have a list of key-value pairs of player names and scores like this:

```
[
    ('ABC', 129),
    ('JON', 205),
    ('DON', 90),
    ('ABC', 300),
    ('DON', 50)
]
```

From this list I want to extract a highscore dictionary like this:

```
{
    'ABC': 300,
    'DON': 90,
    'JON': 205,
}
```

Bonus-Question: How could I create a dictionary of a score history like this and maintain the order of each score-occurence from the original list?

```
{
    'ABC': [129, 300]
    'DON': [90, 50]
    'JON': [205]
}
```

Obviously it is pretty easy to implement the solution with a for-loop, but what is **the most pythonic way**, i.e. how can it be done with **list/dictionary comprehension**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part is a pretty standard thing to do:

```
allscores = [
    ('ABC', 129),
    ('JON', 205),
    ('DON', 90),
    ('ABC', 300),
    ('DON', 50)
]

from collections import defaultdict
scores = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in allscores:
    scores[key].append(val)
```

Once you've got your scores grouped, you can just take the `max` of each list:

```
>>> topscores = dict( (k, max(v)) for k, v in scores.items() )
>>> print(topscores)
{'ABC': 300, 'DON': 90, 'JON': 205}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works:

```
scores_list = [
    ('ABC', 129),
    ('JON', 205),
    ('DON', 90),
    ('ABC', 300),
    ('DON', 50)
]

scores_history_dict = { k1: [v2 for (k2, v2) in scores_list if k1 == k2] for (k1, v1) in scores_list }
print scores_history_dict

highscores_dict = { k1: max([v2 for (k2, v2) in scores_list if k1 == k2]) for (k1, v1) in scores_list }
print highscores_dict
```

Any thoughts? Anyone with a more pythonic, smarter approach?

Comment: That's a good pythonic approach, but I cant help but think it would be faster if he just implements a for loop

Comment: That turns an O(n) problem to an O(n^2) problem. Why not just use a normal loop? It's better than comprehension in this case.